# new project in Android studio is not runnable

Tags: android-studio

I've recently switched form Eclipse to Android studio for developing my Android project, but I faced a problem:
While I create a new project, It seems it be created successfully But it is not runnable at all, My mean is the run button (the green triangle) is disable.
I attached a screen shot of my project in Android studio:
[image]
Also I can't find the `src` and `res` folders in explorer section (the leftside panel).
Can any one help me?  Thanks in advance

Comment: when you create a project, in first page do you have check "Create activity" ?

Comment: @baltov yes, it's checked by default